# createQuery error in netbeans

Tags: mysql, jpql

I have a problem with a query. In mySQL it works but when i go to run in netBeans me by an error. Where am I wrong?

```
public LinkedList<Partita> listaPartGioc(Long id) {
    LinkedList<Partita> lista=new LinkedList<>();
    Query q=getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT * FROM progetto_test.partita WHERE (DATAPARTITA,AVVERSARIO_NOME) IN (SELECT DATAPARTITA,AVVERSARIO_NOME FROM progetto_test.partita_calciatore WHERE calciatoriPartecipanti_ID=id);");
    q.setParameter("id",id);
    lista=(LinkedList<Partita>)q.getResultList();
    return lista;
}
```

[in mySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLzZZ.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dIbs.png)

Comment: Please format your code properly to make it understandable. Use the "code" button `{ }`.

Comment: sorry , done :)

Comment: Try using `WHERE calciatoriPartecipanti_ID=:id` (: before id). Parameters must be preceded by `:`

Comment: I removed all the JSF tags (including jsf from the title) since this question is in no way related to JSF. Sorry...

Comment: I put the: before id and removed the; And now I am from these mistakes
[IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/ka3dog.png[/IMG]